# Difference between presuppose and postulate

Tags: meaning

Presuppose is defined as:

> tacitly assume at the beginning of a line of argument or course of action that something is the case.

Whereas postulate is:

> suggest or assume the existence, fact, or truth of (something) as a basis for reasoning, discussion, or belief.

Is it that you presuppose to gain an advantage in arguments as contrasted with postulating which has nobler intention?

Comment: Presuppositions are not explicitly stated, while postulates are. At least that's how I see it.

Comment: @Laurel Exactly—the key is in that first word, *tacitly*, in the definition of presuppose.

Comment: "Postulate" sounds more scientific.

Comment: What @Laurel said. Or rather, a presupposition need not be (and usually is not) made explicit. A postulate is an explicit assumption or presupposition.

Comment: A 'postulate' explicitly acknowledges the possibility of its falsehood. It's a deliberate, *working* hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly a difference in register, 'postulate' being formal to rarefied, probably most often seen in the scientific register, involving an open declaration, and with a hint at scientific probity (regardless of whether the hypothesis is correct or not):

> **postulate** [verb] [intransitive or transitive]   [formal]
>
> to suggest a theory, idea, etc. as a basic principle from which a
> further idea is formed or developed:
>
> - [+ that]: *It was the Greek astronomer, Ptolemy, who postulated that the earth was at the centre of the universe.*

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/postulate)

And while the two words *are* synonyms

> **presuppose**: ... assume [beforehand] ...

[[Collins English Dictionary; Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/presuppose)]

even when 'presuppose' is used with the meaning 'take as a hypothesis', 'postulate' carries more gravitas and a sense of openness (though sounds overly highbrow in normal conversation).

Further, 'presuppose' is often used with a hint of modality – of tacit concern about the *validity* of a belief, tacit acceptance, and actions based on this:

> **presuppose:** to accept that something is true before it has been proved:
>
> - [+ that]: *You're presupposing that he'll have told her – but
>   he may not have.*

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/presuppose)]

> **presuppose** [verb] ... to take for granted ...

[[Collins](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/presuppose)]

> **presuppose**:.. ***tacitly*** *assume* ... [[OP's Word Hippo definition](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/presupposes.html)] [emphasis mine]

And there is the (modally unmarked) sense

> **presuppose** [verb] [transitive] ...
>
> 2. To require or involve necessarily as an antecedent condition [be predicated upon]:
>
> - *The term 'tax relief' ... presupposes a conceptual metaphor: Taxes are an affliction* (George Lakoff).

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. These words lend themselves to proper discourse. They simply identify what it is that is presupposed or postulated so the discussion may progress with these parameters known. 
The usage may be the original speaker or a response from a discussion member.
I say that "trains are the most efficient form of travel". The response might be "That presupposes that there are trains running where you need to go".
The original speaker is postulating on the efficiency of trains, the response references a supposition that is inherent in the original claim.

Answer (score -1):

Your answer is in your definitions. The presupposition *precedes* conclusion. The postulation is a tentative *conclusion*.

> Presuppose is defined as:
>
> > tacitly assume ***at the beginning of a line* of argument or course of action** that something is the case.
>
> Whereas postulate is:
>
> > suggest or assume the existence, fact, or truth of (something) as a basis for reasoning, discussion, or belief.

We presuppose a single fact which will be a building block in our argument.

Let us **presuppose** that 1+1 = 1. I am one person; the Pope is another person; 1+1 = 1. Therefore, I am the Pope.

We **postulate** **the conclusion** that Greybeard is the Pope and work back from this point.